# two divs next to each other

Tags: css

i'm using plain CSS without any JS Toolkit. The problem is, i'd like to have two separate div lying next to each other.when the second div breaks, it should not lie below the first one. I think my dabblet explains the problem better ;) It is important that the surrounding wrapper div always is at the same size as the containing two divs.

http://dabblet.com/gist/4545815

i already tried it with floating the div1 and div2 to the left.

Answer (score 0):

*div1, 
div2 { 
      display: table-cell 
}*

is a solution for my problem :) 
it is not enough if only div2 has the table-cell property. Resolution can be found here:
http://dabblet.com/gist/4545926

Comment: I know you're not supposed to use tables for layout - I've been doing this a long time and couldn't agree more with that statement... but you are going to run into other problems using `display: table-cell` such as the width expanding to fit content... in which case you will need "inner" divs to constrain the width.  Why not just use a standard table instead.  This lets anybody else know that you are wanting table behavior for the layout.  The only thing you gain by using DIVs is the sense of satisfaction that you used DIVs to achieve table behavior.